# not able to drop database in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to drop database in mysql with following command

```
DROP database db-name;
```

Its take a very long and I faced some issue with the same DB related to table lock and all so I thought to check is there any process active for same DB with the following command

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE DB = 'db-name';
```

its shows one process is there so I kill  that process using `Kill 66`

and then again run the same command

```
SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE DB = 'db-name';
```

so now its shows empty set so I tried again to drop the database using same command but again same result .

I am  using MySQL 8.0 command line client to run all commands , even I use workbench its shows timeout MySQL connection error after few minutes trying to drop the database .

Just to add one more thing I am using root user with all permission , so no issue regarding permissions .

[image: after I run the drop database information schema]

Comment: Yes there are and they are showing in db as null  and command is use db-name , which I am trying to drop.

Comment: Execute `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` in separate CLI window and look what locks the metadata.

Comment: There are other schema on that server , so its shows transactions related to those but none is related to this schema.

Comment: There still could be a query holding onto that schema, while its default database is in some other schema. Cross-schema queries are possible if they reference the tables using [qualified identifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html). Unfortunately, it's hard to find which session is responsible.